# Label text evaluation Jquery

Tags: jquery, label, tex

Why is the label's text is evaluated as not equal to `""` in the below script even when in reality there is not any text in it:

```
              $('label[class*="lb"]').each(function(index){
                  if($(this).text()!=""){
                    a_arr.push($(this).val());
                    alert(index+ "  " + $(this).val());
                  }
              });
```

`$(this).text()!=""` is evaluated true even when the label has no text. Why?

Answer (score 1):

try using `trim` function. Might be there is additional white spaces

```
 if($.trim($(this).text())!="") {
      //your code here
 }
```